# Run a bat script on a distant computer from my computer (Command Prompt)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command

I work on my computer **A**.
I would like to run a batch **script.bat** on my computer **B** (**C:\Documents\script.bat**). The password of the admin session of **B** is **PASSWORD**.

This is my command to execute my batch from computer **B** :

```
start C:\Documents\script.bat
```

Now, I would like to run it with this argument : **3.2.16**
I've tried these 3 commands but it says "incorrect caracter"

```
start C:\Documents\script.bat "3.2.16"
start C:\Documents\script.bat '3.2.16'
start C:\Documents\script.bat 3.2.16
```

Also, I would like to run it from my computer **A**.
Can you help me please ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run a process remotely, you'll either need to use Sysinternals `psexec`, or `wmic`.  The difference is that `psexec` diverts its output to the computer it's invoked from; whereas `wmic` displays a window on the remote PC.

If you're curious, the wmic command syntax is as follows:

```
wmic /node:remotePC /user:remotePC\user /password:password process call create 'cmd /c "c:\path\to\script.bat" "arg1" "arg2"'
```

If you need to view the output of `script.bat`, redirect the output remotely to a text file, then read the text file.

```
wmic /node:remotePC /user:remotePC\user /password:password process call create 'cmd /c blah ^>c:\output.txt'
net use z: \\remotePC\c$ /user:remotePC\user password
type z:\output.txt
del z:\output.txt
net use z: /delete
```

...for example.  But it's probably easier just to download and use `psexec`.